# Force latest version for maven dependencies

Tags: spring, maven

I have the following dependency (only so far) pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency obviously depends on other "dependencies" via it's pom.xml... when maven finished downloading these dependencies I noticed that it didn't grab the latest version of the Spring stuff (4.0.6.RELEASE)... it grabbed a 3.2.x version.

How can I force maven to grab the latest version of the Spring stuff? Do I need to explicitly modify my pom.xml to include all the dependencies or is there some "magic" I can use for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course you need to change your pom cause your pom describes what your build is using which is checked in into your version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `spring-data-jpa` artifact pom file, we can see that it has a parent called `spring-data-parent` with current version [`1.4.2.RELEASE`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.data.build%7Cspring-data-parent%7C1.4.2.RELEASE%7Cpom). It's pom describes dependencies and their versions. Currently spring version is at `3.2.10.RELEASE`

**One way you can possibly accomplish what you want is to add explicit dependency on spring artifacts. But you would still have to define their versions.**

Comment: Thanks... I was hoping that wasn't the case.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you have to explicitly override transitive dependencies' versions if you want a different one.

Answer (score 3):

## Spring "Bill Of Materials"

Salvation may come from special "bill of materials" POMs supported by Maven and published by Spring. Quoting from [Maven "Bill Of Materials" Dependency](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-maven-bom) in their manual:

> It is possible to accidentally mix different versions of Spring JARs when using Maven. For example, you may find that a third-party library, or another Spring project, pulls in a transitive dependency to an older release. If you forget to explicitly declare a direct dependency yourself, all sorts of unexpected issues can arise.
>
> To overcome such problems Maven supports the concept of a "bill of materials" (BOM) dependency. You can import the spring-framework-bom in your dependencyManagement section to ensure that all spring dependencies (both direct and transitive) are at the same version.
>
> ```
> <dependencyManagement>
>   <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
>       <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
>       <type>pom</type>
>       <scope>import</scope>
>     </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
> </dependencyManagement>
> ```

Would this work for you?